Langchain groq returning LangSmithErrors and expected results
I have this simple code where I set my environment variables and then invoke a message from the ChatGroq LLM. I should receive the Chain Output, which I do but in addition I receive 3-4 LangSmith 403 Client Errors. The environment variables are all correct before I make an invoke call so I do not know what the problem is.
Here is my script:
import os
import sys
import time
from langchain_groq import ChatGroq
from langchain_core.messages import HumanMessage, SystemMessage
from langchain_core.output_parsers import StrOutputParser

os.environ["LANGCHAIN_TRACING_V2"] = "true"
os.environ["LANGCHAIN_API_KEY"] = "my_langchain_key"
os.environ["GROQ_API_KEY"] = "my_groq_key"


def getResult(): 
    print("LANGCHAIN_TRACING_V2:", os.environ.get("LANGCHAIN_TRACING_V2"))
    print("LANGCHAIN_API_KEY:", os.environ.get("LANGCHAIN_API_KEY"))
    print("GROQ_API_KEY:", os.environ.get("GROQ_API_KEY"))
    model = ChatGroq(model="llama3-8b-8192")

    data = "Hello"

    messages = [
        SystemMessage(content="Translate this German into Bulgarian: "),
        HumanMessage(content=data),
    ]

    try:
        response = model.invoke(messages)
        print("Model Response:", response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error invoking model: {e}")

    parser = StrOutputParser()

    chain = model | parser

    try:
        output = chain.invoke(messages)
        print("Chain Output:", output)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error invoking chain: {e}")

getResult()

And this is the output I receive:
LANGCHAIN_TRACING_V2: true
LANGCHAIN_API_KEY: my_longchain_key
GROQ_API_KEY: my_groq_key
Failed to batch ingest runs: LangSmithError('Failed to POST https://api.smith.langchain.com/runs/batch in LangSmith API. HTTPError(\'403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://api.smith.langchain.com/runs/batch\', \'{"detail":"Forbidden"}\')')
Model Response: content='Здравей! (Zdravei)' response_metadata={'token_usage': {'completion_tokens': 12, 'prompt_tokens': 23, 'total_tokens': 35, 'completion_time': 0.008747931, 'prompt_time': 0.004093158, 'queue_time': None, 'total_time': 0.012841089}, 'model_name': 'llama3-8b-8192', 'system_fingerprint': 'fp_af05557ca2', 'finish_reason': 'stop', 'logprobs': None} id='run-c96ec363-785c-4295-8eb9-f7beb79cccc1-0' 
usage_metadata={'input_tokens': 23, 'output_tokens': 12, 'total_tokens': 35}
Failed to batch ingest runs: LangSmithError('Failed to POST https://api.smith.langchain.com/runs/batch in LangSmith API. HTTPError(\'403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://api.smith.langchain.com/runs/batch\', \'{"detail":"Forbidden"}\')')
Chain Output: Здравейко! (Zdraveiko!) or simply Здравей! (Zdravei!)
Failed to batch ingest runs: LangSmithError('Failed to POST https://api.smith.langchain.com/runs/batch in LangSmith API. HTTPError(\'403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://api.smith.langchain.com/runs/batch\', \'{"detail":"Forbidden"}\')')

I originally wrote this script in a jupiter notebook, and when i run it there it works flawlessly but once i exported it i started receiving these errors.
